# Android currentTimeMillis

Tags: java, android, system, addition

hello  I have an application that starts a `System.currentTimeMillis` for knowing how long have you been using the app since it started, it works fine

but what I want to do is to add the saved millis to the current system millis, so when loading the data  it will continue from where it stopped.

```
long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis(), millis;
int seconds, minutes, hours;

final Handler h = new Handler(new Callback() 
{
  public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) 
  {

           millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
           seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
           minutes = seconds / 60;
           hours = minutes / 60;
           seconds = seconds % 60;
           minutes = minutes % 60;


       playtime.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
       return false;
    }
});
class firstTask extends TimerTask 
{
     @Override
     public void run() 
     {
         h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
     }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Comment: Do you want it after application restart? Make use of SharedPreference..

Comment: yes, if its restarted or started after 5 hours, when loading data  i want the time to continue.

Comment: are you familiar with SharedPreferences?

Comment: No,  im new to Android programming

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys you have inspired me, i made up a solution

```
long starttime = 0, millis, time_saved = 0;
int seconds, minutes, hours, stime = 0;

final Handler h = new Handler(new Callback() 
{
   public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
       if(stime == 0)
       {
           millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
           seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
           minutes = seconds / 60;
           hours = minutes / 60;
           seconds = seconds % 60;
           minutes = minutes % 60;
       }
       else
       {
           millis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) + time_saved;
           seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
           minutes = seconds / 60;
           hours = minutes / 60;
           seconds = seconds % 60;
           minutes = minutes % 60;
       }


       playtime.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
       return false;
    }
});
class firstTask extends TimerTask 
{
     @Override
     public void run() 
     {
         h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
     }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

in a method

```
private void ST()
{
    time_saved = millis;
}
```

when i want to resume i call this method

```
private void resumetime()
{
    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    stime = 1;
}
```

and it work Excellent

Answer (score 0):

I will explain a sample program to use SharedPreferences.

Create an Android project.

Now, here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    long uptime,starttime,endtime;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // now, I'm getting app uptime in seconds.
         pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Up time:"+pref.getString("time", "0"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         uptime=Long.parseLong(pref.getString("time", "0"));
         starttime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        endtime=System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        uptime=uptime+(endtime-starttime);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("time", ""+uptime);
        editor.commit();
        super.onDestroy();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is to save the time spent in each session and add it to your previous measurement and so on. Shared preferences is a great way to do this. My suggestion would be to make a class like the following:

```
public class AppPreferences {
    private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "com.your.app";

    private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
    private Editor prefsEditor;


    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public AppPreferences(Context context) {
        this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

    }
}
```

And then, put methods like these inside your class:

```
public void saveTimeSpentOnSession(long time){

    long timeSpentSoFar = getTimeSpentSoFar()
    // or you can do
    // long timeSpentSoFar = appSharedPrefs.getLong("timeSpent",0);
    prefsEditor.putLong("timeSpent",time+timeSpentSoFar);
    prefsEditor.commit();

}

public long getTimeSpentSoFar(){
    return appSharedPrefs.getLong("timeSpent",0);
}
```

And whenever you want to call the put / get methods, you simply create an instance of this class like:

```
AppPreferences prefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext()); // in an activity
```

and call

```
prefs.saveTimeSpentOnSession(yourTime);
```